# Remove a value from an Array in a for loop and replace the previous array with the edited array

Tags: php, arrays

i want to eliminate the values from inside the array that has also exist outside the array to form a new array and iterate through the new array to return the first free alphanumeric. 
i tried a for loop but it aint working

this is my code

```
$economyseat = array("5A","5B","5C","5D","5E","5F","6A","6B","6C","6D","6E","6F","7A","7B","7C","7D","7E","7F","8A","8B","8C","8D","8E","8F","9A","9B","9C","9D","9E","9F","10A","10B","10C","10D","10E","10F","11A","11B","11C","11D","11E","11F","12A","12B","12C","12D","12E","12F","13A","13B","13C","13D","13E","13F","14A","14B","14C","14D","14E","14F","15A","15B","15C","15D","15E","15F","16A","16B","16C","16D","16E","16F","17A","17B","17C","17D","17E","17F","18A","18B","18C","18D","18E","18F");
    // $seatnumber = 5A,5B,16C & 18A;
    $seatlength = count($economyseat);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $seatlength; $x++)
    {
        $seat = $economyseat[$x];   
        if ($seatnumber == $seat)
        {
            unset($economyseat[$x]);
            //$economyseat = array_remove_by_value($economyseat, $seat);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is seatnumber exactly? It's commented out but it's relevant to the question. Show us an actual working code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$seatnumber` is another array, how about this...

```
$economyseat = array_diff($economyseat, $seatnumber);
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/203332

Comment: $seatnumber is not an array and i'm having challenges with storing values from database into an array.